# QlikView Using Accumulate 12 steps back for MAT graph, but cant limit date range

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have a line chart which has two dimensions:

`Yearperiod = 201601, 201602, 201603` etc

`Acgroup = FAB, BOB, TOE, QUE` etc

And one expression:

```
SUM(Quantity)
```

This also has Accumulate 12 steps back ticked.

Now the data i get in the chart is correct and is what i want my MAT to be.

However the line chart is showing all dates and i just want to limit it to the last 12.

I have tried doing this with a calculated dimension for Yearperiod like so:

```
=if(Yearperiod >= addmonths(today(),-6), Yearperiod )
```

But this didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be done with set analysis using the aggregation and above functions.

```
sum({<YearPeriod={'>=$(=AddMonths(max(YearPeriod),-11))'}>}aggr(rangesum(above(sum({<YearPeriod=>}Quantity),0,11)),YearPeriod))
```